# Page.js: Instead of Hashbang just Hash?

Tags: javascript, routes, single-page-application

Right now if page.js generates urls they look like this:

```
http://mysite.dev/#!/contact
```

Well I have the option to disable the hashbang completely and make urls look like this:

```
http://mysite.dev/contact
```

But that gives me the problem, that whenever I refresh the URL, I get a failed get request.

I would rather have just a `hash`, like this:

```
http://mysite.dev/#/contact
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd prefer to completely remove `#!` and `#` is to set up your server to always respond to requests with your homepage, no matter the route.  Then your javascript can decide whether to show a page or 404 not found.

After checking the page.js code, it seems that your only option is a hashbang.